# Printing a question does not print the votes for the answer

Tags: support, status-bydesign, voting, printing

When I print a Stack Overflow question, the votes each answer has is not getting printed. As a result, I was not able to differentiate a postive voted answer and a negative voted answer.

This is also the case with accepted answer.

Is this intentional or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) to print a question.

It was developed specifically to overcome the limitations of printing out questions and answers directly from the site.

Comment: @sys: \*cough\* biased \*cough\* ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional. In the stylesheet you'll find the following rule:

```
 div.vote{display:none;}
```

Which hides all the votes. This includes the accepted answer check mark.

Comment: Why is this intentional ?  I think this is a necessary feature.

Comment: Order of the answers will by default be highest voted down with accepted up top. You can use a marker pen to real-world the checkmark you think works best too. Offline interaction. @the

Answer (score 0):

You can work-around this by using a browser screenshot as mentioned in [this SU question](https://superuser.com/q/120266/35237), allowing you to print the question just the way it is displayed at your screen.